# disable button not working in jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, button

I want to disable the submit button after the user clicks on the submit button in the HTML form. But form redirects directly to the next page without disabling the button.

The ideal sequence is:

1. User clicks the submit button
2. Validation is performed
3. Submit button disables
4. Form Data is submitted to the database/ spreadsheet
5. User is redirected to thank you page

With the following code, the only issue is that the submit button is not getting disabled and everything else is working perfectly. Please suggest an alternative to fix the code. I am using WordPress which runs on jquery 1.4.1. So,  $input.prop('disabled', true) also did not work

**HTML:**

```
    <form id="test-form" method="post" name="test-form" action="">
<div>
<input class="input-field" name="Name" required type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
</div>

<div>
<input class="input-field" name="Phone" required type="number" placeholder="Enter number" />
</div>

<div><button id="submit-form" class="btn" type="submit" name="submit-form">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var $form = $('form#test-form');
url = 'https://abcd';


 $form.submit(function(e) {
  $('submit-form').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(function() {
            location.replace("/thank-you/");
        });
e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Comment: `$('submit-form')` should be `$('#submit-form')`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Also note that jQuery 1.4.1 is *massively* out of date. You really need to update it.

Comment: if you're just going to redirect the user immediately when the AJAX returns then you really needn't bother with AJAX. The whole point of AJAX is to allow the user to _stay on the same page_. You could just ditch the AJAX, submit the form normally and make the server issue a redirect command instead.

Comment: P.S. If you claim your jQuery version is dependent on WordPress then your WordPress install must also be extremely out of date as well.

Comment: Hi @Hackerz,  are you using jquery-validation plugin?

Answer (score 1):

you are given id was wrong. try this

```
$(function(){
var $form = $('#test-form');
url = 'https://abcd';
 $form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
  $('#submit-form').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(function() {
            location.replace("/thank-you/");
        });
      });
      });
```

Comment: This also did not disable the button. If the button is disabled immediately after the successful submission and validation, users will not be able to submit the form again and again. I am still trying to debug the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Hackerz, Please try this plugin     http://javascript-coder.com/jsform/jquery-disable-button-on-click-submit.phtml

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').attr("disabled", true);
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            complete: function(response){
                $('#button').attr("disabled", false);
            },
        });
```